# Check JSON Response nil in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I am using swiftyjson for JSON Parsing.

My problem is when url is not valid or url is returns any error then app crash

here is code

```
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) { () -> Void in

        let url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=25&playlistId=\(self.playId)&key=AIzaSyB6LBckj5oqkbmroNPIhm7zru9vmsZR-w0"

        self.json = JSON(data: (NSData(contentsOfURL: (NSURL(string: url)!)))!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) // App is crash on this line


 // END
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
```

How to check url is valid or url is contain error

Comment: You should use the `error` parameter

Comment: i also use this but no work app is crash

Comment: If you use `!`, your program can abort. Try replacing your `!` with `?` and getting your program to compile that way.

Comment: try but not force apply ?

Comment: First of all, you should be using `swift2` nowadays (update your xcode) and proper error handling. Your current code ignores errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use try-catch something like this to prevent the crash:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) { () -> Void in

        let url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=25&playlistId=\(self.playId)&key=AIzaSyB6LBckj5oqkbmroNPIhm7zru9vmsZR-w0"

    if let JSONObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData((NSData(contentsOfURL: (NSURL(string: url)!)))?, options: .AllowFragments) as? [[String: AnyObject]],

    }    


 // END
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
```

Comment: not work when i enter wrong play list id app crash on -- if let JSONObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .AllowFragments) as? [[String: AnyObject]]  -- this line

Comment: I have updated the answer by using optional binding.